# Fibonacci Sequence in Java taking too long?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm trying to find the sum of the Fibonacci sequence in Java, but the run time is taking way too long (or is it suppose to?). This slows down anytime I use an integer past 40.

Note: At 50, a negative value is returned which boggles my mind.

Any advice?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    //Find Fibonacci sequence
    int sum=getSum(50);
    System.out.println("Sum of Fibonacci Numbers is " + sum); 
}
static int getSum(int n){
    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n==1 || n==2) return 1;
    else return getSum(n-1) + getSum(n-2);
}
```

Comment: use long instead of int to solve negative values at 50

Comment: Yes. Figure the potential outcome of fib(50); and compare that with the values that java ints allow. This might also give you a clue about the number of method calls you are triggering ... giving you some insight on the "bad" performance.

Comment: it takes to long, because you have two recursions. this means for input n the function getSum will be called about 2^(n-1) -1 times (you can calculate the precise value on your own).

Comment: What does "too long" mean exactly? How long?

Comment: You should use Long instead of int. Secondly this algoritm has one big disadvantage - you compute each number twice, while you only need it once. For loop would be more effective here unfortunatelly. Recursion is good only for small numbers.

Comment: @Beri Nonsense. Please argument your points or post relevant links. Why is recursion good only for small numbers?

Comment: Please use long datatype instead of integer. Because integer length is short less than long.

Comment: Not at all, for each getSum method you need to find a fibonachi value for each function call, whereas using for loop you use one int only twice. Recursion is not always a good solution for big numbers.

Comment: @m0skit0 Fib(50) is 12.586.269.025; and max int is 2.147.483.647
So, what did you just say?

Comment: @Beri: In this *particular* case recursion isn't suitable - but that doesn't make your claim universally true by any means.

Comment: Basically, this algorithm is exponential; an iterative approach is linear. And yes, `long` - or better, `BigInteger` - would work better here.

Comment: @EddyG Right, my mistake, I don't know what I was calculating. No need for that swag attitude though.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, if i recall your deleted comment, that one wasn't exactly polite either.

Comment: To improve the runtime while still using recursion, memoization can be used, although that's an overkill here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `n > 2`, an invocation of your `getSum(n)` recursively invokes itself twice.  Each of those invocations may recurse further.  The total number of method invocations scales as `2^n`, and `2^50` is a very large number.  This poor scaling reflects the fact that the simple-minded recursive approach ends up needlessly recomputing the same results (e.g. fib(4)) a great many times, and it is why your program slows down so rapidly as you increase `n`.

The negative return value you get after a certain point arises from exceeding the limits of data type `int`.  You could get a larger limit with a wider data type, presumably `long`.  If that's not enough then you would need to go to something like `BigInteger`, at a substantial performance penalty.

Comment: It scales as about 1.618^n, not 2^n, but otherwise this is the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use long instead of int if you want to calculate the 50th Fibonacci number. The 50th Fibonacci number is 12586269025 and exceeds the maximum value of int (see http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html).

A non-recursive algorithm is likely going to be faster, see http://planet.jboss.org/post/fibonacci_sequence_with_and_without_recursion for the different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

As the others already stated you should use `long` for the calculated fibonacci value, as the number will get very long very fast.

If your formost priority is performance you could use the following formula:

[image]

with

[image]

(Idea taken from Linear Algebra lecture, actual formula taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Dynamic_Programming).)
That way you will get the n-th fibonacci number in constant time (depending on the calculation of the n-th powers in the formula).

---

The following code calculates the fibonacci sequenc of the first 93 numbers with no waiting time (on my machine):

```
private static final double SQRT_FIVE = Math.sqrt(5);
private static final double GOLDEN_RATIO = (1 + SQRT_FIVE) / 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 92; i++) {
        System.out.println("fib(" + i + ") = " + calculateFibonacci(i));
    }
}

public static long calculateFibonacci(int n) {
    double numerator = Math.pow(GOLDEN_RATIO, n) - Math.pow(1-GOLDEN_RATIO, n);
    double denominator = SQRT_FIVE;

    // This cast should in general work, as the result is always an integer. 
    // Floating point errors may occur!
    return (long)(numerator/denominator); 
}
```

From the 94-th number on the long is no longer sufficent and you need to use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and fitting math operations, as the `double` calculations may produce calculation errors with such big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

first, use a long instead of an int, to avoid overflow.

Secondly, use a non-recursive algorithm, as a recursive one exists in exponential time I think. A well designed non-recursive one will solve in linear time (I think).

Example non-recursive

```
static long getSum(int n){

    long[] fibonacci = new long[n];
    fibonacci[0] = 1;
    fibonacci[1] = 1;

    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n==1 || n==2) return 1;

    for(int i = 2; i < n;i++){
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1]+ finonacci[i-2];
    }
    return fibonacci[n-1];
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

If you plan to call this method frequently, it might be prudent to store the array outside of the method, so that it is a simple lookup when doing this. This would provide a constant time solution for numbers that have already been calculated at least once. an example of that is below.

```
static long[] fibonacci= {1,1};
static long getSum(int n){

    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n==1 || n==2) return 1;

    int old_length = fibonacci.length;

    if(fibonacci.length < (n-1)){
        fibonacci = Arrays.copyOf(fibonacci,n);
    }else{
        return fibonacci[n-1];
    }



    for(int i = old_length; i < n;i++){
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1]+ finonacci[i-2];
    }
    return fibonacci[n-1];
}
```

Again, the example is untested, so a bit of debugging might be required.

Here is a linear time implementation of the algorithm that uses a constant overhead, instead of linear overhead.

```
static long getSum(int n){

    long currentNum = 0;
    long previousNum = 1;
    long previousNum2 = 1;

    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n==1 || n==2) return 1;

    for(int i = 2; i < n;i++){
        currentNum = previousNum+ previousNum2;
        previousNum2 = previousNum;
        previousNum = currentNum;
    }
    return currentNum;
}
```

Comment: A recursive approach with memoization could run in linear time, with linear overhead -- the same as the method you have presented, in fact.  Linear overhead for a non-recursive implementation is sub-optimal, however, as you can do the job with constant overhead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Added another example with external storage of the array, so that values can simply be looked up if already calculated. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: No.  It doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity whether the array is allocated locally or globally.  It is the use of an array to store *all* of the results up to the target value that makes this approach have linear overhead.  You don't need to do that, because at each step you need to know only the two previous values in the sequence, not any prior ones.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, I see what you mean now. I was thinking in terms of time rather than memory space.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Added one with constant overhead. This more what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solutions don't necessarily have to be slow. If you were to use this tail-recursive solution, you'd save up a lot of memory and still achieve great speed (e.g. Fib(10000) runs in 1.1s on my machine).

Here *n* is the sequence number for which you're calculating Fibonacci number, while *f0* and *f1* are two accumulators, for previous and current Fibonacci numbers respectively.

```
public class FibonacciRec {
    public static int fib(int n, int f0, int f1) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return f0;
        } else if (n == 1){
            return f1;
        } else {
            return fib(n-1, f1, f0+f1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fib(10, 0, 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the recursive approach as is, cache results of calculation in an array or map. When you have calculated one Fibonacci for n, save that result.  Then, in your method first see if you have the result and return that if you do.  Otherwise, make the recursive call(s).  Here's an example: recursion is still used and it is quite fast:

```
public static Map<Long,Long> cache = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    cache = new HashMap<Long,Long>();
    cache.put(0L,0L);
    cache.put(1L,1L);
    cache.put(2L,1L);
    Long sum=getSum(50L);
    System.out.println("Sum of Fibonacci Numbers is " + sum); 

}

static Long getSum(Long n){
    if (cache.containsKey(n)) { return cache.get(n); }
    else {
        Long fib = getSum(n-1) + getSum(n-2);
        cache.put(n, fib);
        return fib;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is an example of the memoization that @Tarik refers to.  (That's the better term, probably--I called it a cache in my example).